# 2D Array Malloc

Tags: c

Below is a part of a longer code where malloc'ing for a 2D array is done. Could anyone tell if this is correct? If I introduce static values, the code works fine. Else, seg faults...

```
enum { LEN = 1024*8 };

char **tab = NULL;
int cur_LEN = LEN;
int count_lineMax = 0;


tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));
      memset(tab, 0, count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));

if(tab == NULL && count_lineMax) {
    printf("Mem_check\n");
    exit(1);
}

for(k=0;k<count_lineMax;k++) {
    tab[k] = malloc(cur_LEN*sizeof(*tab[k]));
    memset(tab[k], 0, cur_LEN*sizeof(*tab[k]));

    if(tab[k] == NULL) {
        printf("Mem_check*\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
for(l=0;l<count_lineMax;l++) {
    free(tab[l]);
}
free(tab);
```

Comment: count_lineMax is zero so you allocate nothing.

Comment: Looks OK; works for me even when setting count_lineMax. Having said that you could allocate a single block.

Comment: You are getting a seg fault because you are allocating 0 bytes and not checking (malloc is going to return null every time). If you actually want a 2D array, you can allocate the entire block at once in one line. If you want an array of variable-length C-strings (which is kind of what it looks like you want), you need to malloc the first list with a lineMax > 0 and then allocate enough space at each element for the variable-length C-string at that location (don't forget to include an extra char for '\0')

Comment: And you need to check the memory allocation before using `memset()` on it -- and you should consider using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` since it will do the zeroing for you.  It also is not clear that you benefit from zeroing `tab` since the next thing you do is allocate values into the recently zeroed space.

Comment: Also, note that `malloc(0)` may return a NULL pointer or it may return a valid pointer (that you _can't_ dereference because it points to zero bytes of memory); it depends on the implementation of `malloc()`.

Comment: @Jonathan: I checked allocation before using memset() and it does return NULL. Thanks for the help. Is there a workaround?

Comment: The data structure you've created is not a 2D array. It's an array of pointers to [the first elements of] 1D arrays.

Comment: @gyan - I was overzealous ... as Jonathan stated, many malloc(3) implementations these days return something more than 0 bytes, but not as many as you expected since you /asked/ for zero bytes. You need to ask for the correct number of bytes in your array.

Comment: The workaround is 'do not allocate zero bytes'; or, if you must, then do not try to access any of the bytes because you did not allocate any.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks a lot. I learnt so much more about malloc today. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Jason: I take note of your point about malloc return values. Thanks.

Comment: @R: could you  please explain?

Comment: A 2D array is an array of arrays - a single contiguous object in memory. Your data structure is an array of pointers, where each pointer points to the beginning of a "row" stored at some separate location.

Comment: @R: char *tab=NULL; tab=malloc(size, sizeof(tab)); is same as the 1D Array char tab[size]. Right? Similarly, I thought what I have done as you have pointed out, an array of pointers simulating a 2D array. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
int count_lineMax = 0;

tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));
```

What is this? You are gonna malloc 0 bytes?

Comment: I should have added this loop as well:  while(fgets(line, cur_LEN, file1) != NULL) {
                count_lineMax++;         
        }

Comment: have you added that loop befor malloc.??

Comment: oops! I meant before malloc! Sorry

Comment: still you have problem ?then please compile your code with -g option & run with valgrind. (if you dont know valgrind then search it on google)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to build the table while reading lines.  One uses the property of `realloc()` that if its first argument is a null pointer, it will behave like `malloc()` and allocate the requested space (so the code can be self-starting, using `realloc()` alone).  That code might look like:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { LEN = 1024*8 };

static void error(const char *fmt, ...);
static char *xstrdup(const char *str);

int main(void)
{
    char line[LEN];
    char **tab = NULL;
    int tabsize = 0;
    int lineno = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        if (lineno >= tabsize)
        {
            size_t newsize = (tabsize + 2) * 2;
            char **newtab = realloc(tab, newsize * sizeof(*newtab));
            if (newtab == 0)
                error("Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", newsize * sizeof(*newtab));
            tab = newtab;
            tabsize = newsize;
        }
        tab[lineno++] = xstrdup(line);
    }

    /* Process the lines */
    for (int i = 0; i < lineno; i++)
        printf("%d: %s", i+1, tab[i]);

    /* Release the lines */
    for (int i = 0; i < lineno; i++)
        free(tab[i]);
    free(tab);

    return(0);
}

static void error(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(1);
}

static char *xstrdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *copy = malloc(len);
    if (copy == 0)
        error("Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", len);
    memmove(copy, str, len);
    return(copy);
}
```

The alternative uses `malloc()` explicitly when the table is empty, and is most simply coded as:

```
int main(void)
{
    char line[LEN];
    int tabsize = 4;
    int lineno = 0;
    char **tab = malloc(tabsize * sizeof(*tab));

    if (tab == 0)
        error("Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", tabsize * sizeof(*tab));

    ...
```

Everything else can remain untouched.

Note that it can be convenient to have functions `xmalloc()` and `xrealloc()` which are guaranteed never to return a null pointer because they report an error instead:

```
static void *xmalloc(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *space = malloc(nbytes);
    if (space == 0)
        error("Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", nbytes);
    return(space);
}

static void *xrealloc(void *buffer, size_t nbytes)
{
    void *space = realloc(buffer, nbytes);
    if (space == 0)
        error("Failed to reallocate %zu bytes of memory\n", nbytes);
    return(space);
}
```

In the long term (big programs), this cuts down on the total number of times you write 'out of memory' error messages.  On the other hand, if you must recover from memory allocation failures (save the user's work, etc), then this is not an appropriate strategy.

The code above creates a ragged array; different entries in `tab` have different lengths.  If you want homogeneous lengths (as in the original code), then you have to replace or modify the `xstrdup()` function to allocate the maximum length.

You might have noticed that the code in `xstrdup()` used `memmove()` instead `strcpy()`.  That's because `strlen()` already measured how long the string is, so there's no need for the copy code to test each byte to see whether it needs copying.  I used `memmove()` because it can never go wrong, even if the strings overlap, even though in this context it is clear that the strings can never overlap and so `memcpy()` - which is not guaranteed to work correctly if the strings overlap - could have been used since the strings cannot overlap.

The strategy of allocating `(oldsize + 2) * 2` new entries means that the memory reallocation code is exercised often enough during testing, without unduly impacting performance in production.  See [The Practice of Programming](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/index.html) by Kernighan and Pike for a discussion of why this is a good idea.

I almost always use a set of functions similar to the `error()` function because it dramatically simplifies error reporting.  The functions I normally use are part of a package that records and reports the program name (from `argv[0]`) as well, and that has a fairly wide range of alternative behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I'd have to print this out and go over all of it carefully. Thanks Again.